# Update JSON data from Python into Firebase

Tags: python, json

I have data from my sensors that I control with my `Raspberry Pi`. I packed this data into a `JSON` file. With `Python` I want to write a program that updates this data hourly and uploads it to `Firebase`.

My code looks like this so far:

```
from firebase import firebase
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open (thejsondata) as data_file:
    data=json.load(data_file)
pprint(data)

firebase=firebase.FirebaseApplication("...")

r2 = requests.put("https://testproject...",data=jsondata)
print(r2)
```

How do I manage to upload it to `Firebase` every hour?

Comment: You could configure [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) jobs if you're using linux

Comment: okay, can you help me? :)

Comment: Sure. [This](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) might help you get started